# Gender Pronouns for inanimate objects

Tags: word-usage

Is there a term for using gender pronouns for inanimate objects?

Comment: Why should there be?

Comment: `Personification`, `anthromorphism`, and `zoomorphism` all seem to possibly apply.

Comment: e.g. referring to a ship as "she"?

Comment: It's called "covert gender". Like _cat_ and _dog_ in English, where the default personal pronouns are _she_ and _he_, respectively, as Whorf pointed out.

Comment: @JohnLawler Citation needed? The default pronoun for a cat or a dog is _it_, unless the sex of the animal is known. However, many speakers will use _he_ until corrected.

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, that's JL's point, English speakers will tend to use 'he' for dogs and 'she' for cats until corrected. With respect to citation, there's the appeal to numbers, namely, everyone knows this. If that's not convincing, just listen to what people do.

Comment: @Mitch I've never heard anyone default to _she_ for a cat with an unknown gender. Citation needed please.

Comment: At least in linguistics, everybody's read this; it's  75 years old. "Grammatical Categories", Benjamin Lee Whorf, 1945.  _Language_ 21: 1, pp. 1-11. BTW, as an owner at one time or another of a female dog and a male cat, I can vouch for the default values.

Comment: "... machines are more likely to be "she" when they do not run well" Isabel Crouch, 1976, p.11 https://books.google.co.in/books?id=X1OvAAAAIAAJ

Answer (score 2):

I would call it **gendering**:

> The assigning or attributing of a gender to someone or something; division, classification, or differentiation according to gender.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gendering)</sub>

Here are some examples:

> I know gendering of vehicles (cars, boats, trains, plains, etc) is actually fairly common in fiction (I haven't seen/heard about it much in real life), but it's usually male characters that are naming them and calling them by gender pronouns.
>   <sub>[Fifty Shades of Why](http://50shadesofwhy.tumblr.com/post/102590481261/i-know-gendering-of-vehicles-cars-boats-trains)</sub>

> These sorts of feminine motherhood associations led to the gendering.
>   <sub>Quora: [Why are almost all ships considered 'female'?](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-almost-all-ships-considered-female)</sub>

> - If I demonstrate instances of humans gendering boats as masculine and feminine just like they do with people in a way that's totally separate from sex will you admit you're wrong and I'm right? [...] — /u/halfback910
> - You can provide me with instances of humans gendering humans. I disagree with that as equally as i disagree with gendering boats or rubbish bins. [...] — /u/Belrick_NZ
> - The fact remains that we DO gender things. And as long as we ARE gendering things, we should apply our conventions uniformly, right? [...] — /u/halfback910
>
> <sub>Reddit: [If You Guys Like the Way "It's Okay to be White" f***s with the Left, You Should try "There Are Only Two Sexes"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anarcho_Capitalism/comments/7akqjn/if_you_guys_like_the_way_its_okay_to_be_white/)</sub>

Comment: I don't think the dictionary means to refer to inanimate objects. "Something" likely means an animal.

Comment: @Kris Animals don’t get assigned genders/sexes- they come that way. The process of finding out the sex is called [sexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_sexing). (Thankfully a search for “chick sexing”, as risky as it sounds, doesn’t bring up any dirty results .)

Comment: Funny, what we are talking about here is not about sexing an animal. Try to get the drift, Laurel.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on *why* you want to add a gender, it is an example of [**anthropomorphization**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthropomorphize):

> to attribute human form or personality to things not human

Most of the time, the gender assigned is female. However, some inanimate objects are given a male gender.

From an article called ["Metaphorical Gender in English: Feminine Boats, Masculine Tools and Neuter Animals"](https://www.druide.com/en/reports/metaphorical-gender-english-feminine-boats-masculine-tools-and-neuter-animals) (emphasis in the example sentences is mine):

> This phenomenon of imposing masculinity or femininity on sexless objects and abstract concepts is used for poetic effect in order to personify objects or show strong emotional involvement with them, especially when calling an object *it* seems too cold. Since English lacks grammatical gender, English speakers are given creative licence to personify objects as whichever gender they choose. The following are some examples of metaphorical gender in English usage:
>
> On *her* maiden voyage, the Bismarck collided with another ship but *she* sustained no damage.
>
> "My car, *she’s* a beauty."
>
> I’ll tell you what I found—one of our old hay knives. I got *him* out and cleaned *him* up and put a new handle on *him*.